# Different behaviour on iPhone and iPad

Tags: iphone

I have a UITextView for which I want left/right/top/bottom content margins and the code I used is:

```
// Set the paddings
UIEdgeInsets aUIEdge = [aTextView contentInset]; 
aUIEdge.left = 15;
aUIEdge.right = 15;
aUIEdge.top = 10;
aUIEdge.bottom = 10;
aTextView.contentInset = aUIEdge;
```

But this gives me correct output in iPhone and not in iPad. What to do, give some clue?

Comment: Just select the code parts and press the `010` button to get it formatted. Use the *preview* to check it before posting.

Comment: What do you mean by right or wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked with a IF statement:
    // Set the paddings
    UIEdgeInsets aUIEdge = [aTextView contentInset];
    if (<>) {
        aUIEdge.left = 15;
        aUIEdge.right = 10;
    }
    else {
        aUIEdge.left = 5;
        aUIEdge.right = 15;
    }